# Get ID from dynamically generated LinkButton

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0

I am generating button dynamically in the code behind and assign ID to it from a database table.

```
Dim subjectLinkButton As LinkButton = New LinkButton()
subjectLinkButton.Attributes.Add("ID", doc.InboxId)
subjectLinkButton.Text = doc.ReceivedSubject
AddHandler subjectLinkButton.Click, AddressOf subjectLinkButton_Click
```

When I click on the button, I use this

```
Dim btn As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
Me.debugTest.InnerText = "Button ID:" & btn.ID
```

I get this error: 
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Inbox.subjectLinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 1):

Changed Attributes.Add to

```
        subjectLinkButton.CommandName = "inbox_id"
        subjectLinkButton.CommandArgument = doc.InboxId
```

and

```
        Dim btn As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
        Me.debugTest.InnerText = "Button: " & btn.CommandName & " " & btn.CommandArgument
```

Comment: Would probably be a little cleaner as an attached property but good job on solving your own issue!